# Google authentication for android is failing with API 10 error

Tags: android, firebase, authentication

I have integrated the google signin using firebase authentication. The authentication works properly in debug environment but fails in release mode.
So far i have added the release SHA1 key of the certificate as well as the App Signing Certificate SHA1 key, but in release mode it gives API error 10.
Note, if i directly run the app in release mode from android studio, it is working fine. But when uploading to google internal sharing and then downloading and checking the authentication, it is giving API 10 error.

```
Unable to figure out what else can be the issue. Can anyone kindly help here
```

Comment: Since you're using Android, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithGoogle). It's a working solution.